# Zxing change the action intent

Tags: android, zxing

I added the Zxing library to my android app but there is a problem.
When you already have a bar code scanner installed it presents you
with a popup.
I don't want this to happen and changed the the action intent.
This is working, but when I open my app for the first time and select
the bar code scanner it crashes.
When I open it for the second time everything works fine.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Can can see the crash log here: http://www.everybodylikespenguins.nl/log.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already answered this a few times on the mailing list. As I said, you need to pay attention to `ActivityNotFoundException`.

```
09-27 16:52:54.046 E/AndroidRuntime( 4949): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {nl.everybodylikespenguins/com.google.zxing.client.android.HelpActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-27 16:52:54.046 E/AndroidRuntime( 4949):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
09-27 16:52:54.046 E/AndroidRuntime( 4949):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
09-27 16:52:54.046 E/AndroidRuntime( 4949):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2789)
09-27 16:52:54.046 E/AndroidRuntime( 4949):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2895)
09-27 16:52:54.046 E/AndroidRuntime( 4949):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.showHelpOnFirstLaunch(CaptureActivity.java:595)
09-27 16:52:54.046 E/AndroidRuntime( 4949):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:169)
09-27 16:52:54.046 E/AndroidRuntime( 4949):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-27 16:52:54.046 E/AndroidRuntime( 4949):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
```

Android throws this when you start an intent for which there is no app, and that's what's happening here. You need to handle this yourself by catching the exception and, maybe, sending the user to Market to download.

This is exactly what the code in `android-integration` in `zxing` does, which is why I also already told you to look at that.

Comment: I've got it working now, you where right it was looking for the "HelpActivity". Thx for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @GeorgeW, I deleted the reference to the HelpActivity in the code. If you have the same problem as I had you need to search your code for the activity causing the ActivityNotFoundException. Fix the reference or delete it. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: @Daniel,  I was in process of upgrading cordova and plugins. Can't say for sure, but a combination of removing and adding library project,  updating in Zxing related intent xml in manifest and other cocktails ward off the problem for me. Thanks for your response.